# Get full url address on Safari

Tags: safari, macos, url

In Yosemite, the new Safari "hides" part of the URL, how could I show it without going to the address bar every time?

e.g. **`https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=p9lIVJbjCYiX8QfnpoCgBQ#q=stackexchange`** becomes **`google.com.br`**

[image: shorten]

[image: open]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution, right after posting...

Go to Safari → Preferences → Advanced → Show Full Website URL

[image: Preferences]

[image: Show full url]